# A 10 second delay when accessing files in my system

Tags: filemanager

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. When I first click the `files` icon on my favorites bar, it takes maybe 10 seconds to open the window. Once it is open, then it works as normal.

This may be unrelated but it seems similar: When I use the `Screenshot` software to take a screenshot (with "select area to grab"), after the screenshot there is a 10 second period of waiting before the dialog box appears and allows me to choose a save location.

The same thing happens when I am on a website and I click an "upload from computer" link. Again, there is a 10 second delay before any kind of file dialog box opens.

Does anyone recognize this and have any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: You must have a slow HDD.

Comment: I don't know enough to confirm that. But everything else feels very fast - except from these things I have mentioned above. And my machine is a HP Spectre X360 which I think is a decent laptop.